# Loop images next to each other from an array( horizontal) Javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I´m playing with DOM and JS.
Can someone show me an hint how to get the images NEXT TO EACH OTHER, not  overwrite..
like: randomnumberimage1 randomnumberimage2 randomnumberimage3 etc...

```
 <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Söka Tärning</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Klicka för att fylla på arrayen med slumptal.</p>

    <button onclick="slumpatal()">Slumpa</button>
    <button onclick="sortering()">Sortera Högsta--->Lägsta</button>
    <button onclick="hittanummer(3)">Hitta 3:or</button>

    <p id="allatal"></p>
    <p id="vinst"></p>
    <p id="sokt_tal"></p>

    <img id="tarningsbilder" src="bild1.png" alt="tärning" />
    <img id="helavektorn" src="bild1.png" alt="tärning" />
     <script>
         var alla_tal_i_vektorn = [];
         var antal_sökta_tal = 0;

         function slumpatal() {
             document.getElementById("vinst").innerHTML = "";

             slumptal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
             alla_tal_i_vektorn.push(slumptal);



             for (var i = 0; i < alla_tal_i_vektorn.length; i++) {
                 document.getElementById("tarningsbilder").src = "bild" + alla_tal_i_vektorn[i] + ".png";

             }

             document.getElementById("allatal").innerHTML = alla_tal_i_vektorn;
             document.getElementById("tarningsbilder").src = "bild" + slumptal + ".png";
             if (slumptal == 3)
                 document.getElementById("vinst").innerHTML = "en trea yieppie!!";
         }

         function sortering() {
             alla_tal_i_vektorn.sort(function (a, b) { return b - a });
             document.getElementById("vinst").innerHTML = alla_tal_i_vektorn;
         }

         function hittanummer(sökt_tal) {
             antal_sökta_tal = 0;
             for (var i = 0; i < alla_tal_i_vektorn.length; i++) {
                 if (alla_tal_i_vektorn[i] == sökt_tal)
                     antal_sökta_tal += 1;
             }
             document.getElementById("sokt_tal").innerHTML = "det fanns " + antal_sökta_tal + "st treor!";
         }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for all kind of help

Regards
Tha Pig

Find a snice solution by myself..! Her´s the code:

> Söka och sortera tärning
>
> Klicka för att fylla på arrayen med slumptal.
>
> ```
> <button onclick="myFunction()">Slumpa</button>
> <button onclick="sortering()">Sortera Högsta-->Lägsta</button>
> <button onclick="findById(3)">Hitta 3:or</button>
>
> <p id="demo"></p>
> <p id="vinst"></p>
> <p id="sokt_tal"></p>
>
>
>
> <script>
>     var all_numbers = [];
>     **var alla_bilder = [];**
>     var nums = 0;
>
>     function myFunction() {
>         document.getElementById("vinst").innerHTML = "";
>
>         slumptal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
>         all_numbers.push(slumptal);
>         ***alla_bilder.push("<img src=bild" + slumptal + ".png\>");***
>
>         **document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = alla_bilder;**
>         document.getElementById("demo").src = "bild" + slumptal + ".png";
>
>
>
>         if (slumptal == 3)
>             document.getElementById("vinst").innerHTML = "en trea yieppie!!";
>     }
>
>     function sortering() {
>         all_numbers.sort(function (a, b) { return b - a });
>         document.getElementById("vinst").innerHTML = all_numbers;
>     }
>
>     function findById(num) {
>         nums = 0;
>         for (var i = 0; i < all_numbers.length; i++) {
>             if (all_numbers[i] == num)
>                 nums += 1;
>         }
>         document.getElementById("sokt_tal").innerHTML = "det fanns " + nums + "st treor!";
>     }
> </script> </body> </html>
> ```

Thanks
Tha Pig

Comment: Can you explain what you are attempting to do with your javascript?

Comment: Well, it´s small "tools", hopefully helps newbies in different aspects of programming, regarding DOM, JS etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript
node.parentNode.childNodes[]

or

JQUERY
$('selector').siblings()

After you get the sibling you can check the element node is img.

Comment: I´m not sure how to implement it. And still wonder if thats the easiest way. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Hi! I´m answer myself. I made it efficient and smooth with an new array.